# Notation: Why Is the "Is Member of" Symbol in These Sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Questions:

1. Given $ A = \{ \in, a \} $, $ B = \{ ab \} $, find $ A^2 $, $ B^3 $, and $ AB $
2. Given $ A = \{ \in, a \} $, $ B = \{ ab \} $, determine $ A^* $, $ B^* $, and $ B+ $

So I was given these two questions to solve. I think I know how to solve them in general, but I am confused as to why set A has a "is member of" symbol ($\in$) in it. I've never seen this before and was wondering if it's some special type of notation or if rather the symbol is merely an arbitary element.

Comment: Pleast take a look at some general guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) on this site, with a specific emphasis on [formatting and writing](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992) your question, where it says "Make your question visible, searchable, accessible. Don't force someone to click on an external link just to see your question, it should be immediately visible after clicking on your title."

Comment: And you can use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset the mathematical symbols.

Comment: It’s entirely possible that it’s simply a character in the alphabet $A$, perhaps chosen to make the point that anything can be an element of a formal alphabet.

Comment: Yeah I think this is the case.

Comment: Agreed with asker that this is abuse of notation that confuses rather than teaches. Imagine if we write a set $\{\{,:,,,\}$. What are the elements? Perhaps $\{,$ is one element just like $ab$?

Answer (score 5):

From context, it's probably [the empty string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_string), which is commonly denoted $\epsilon$ or $\varepsilon$ (epsilon), but which someone who's not very good with symbols might confuse with $\in$.

(Historically, the symbol $\in$ did *evolve* from epsilon, so it's not too embarrassing a mistake.)

Comment: Hmm it might be, but I am looking ahead in my notes to the Words and Languages section and my professor is using lambda ($ \lambda $) to denote the null string/empty word. I might have to email him in order to clarify.

Comment: He said that epsilon is the null character, not a string because it is the element in a set. What is the difference between a "null character" and a "null string"?

Comment: That's not a distinction typically made by people studying formal language theory, so I'm not sure. We do distinguish between *characters*, which are elements of the alphabet, and *strings*, which are sequences of characters. But there's no such thing as a "null character" in that sense. Also, people are often sloppy about the difference between characters and strings of length $1$.

Comment: Maybe the professor misunderstood you, or got his phrasing wrong, and meant to clarify that epsilon is a null string and not the empty set? But I'm just guessing and these are really questions you should be asking your professor.